# Sending picture from my phone (iOS) to Surface Pro (Windows 10) via BLE

Tags: ios, swift, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, surface-pro

I am trying to send picture from my phone (iOS) to Surface Pro (Windows 10) via BLE. After successfully establishing the connection, I get some detailed peripheral information.
i have two question :

- which service and characteristics is responsible for sending data like picture to w10 , i think it should be this ( service : "34b1cf4d-1069-4ad6-89b6-e161d79be4d0",
  charac : "34b1cf4d-1069-4ad6-89b6-e161d79be4d2")?
- we guess I found the services and the charac, how I can send a photo of an iphone that the size must be minimum 12mo in a single frame, I looked on the internet for a microsoft document which must explain or define these standards but I found nothing.

i'm using core bluetooth in iOS(swift 5)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a default profile/service/characteristic in BLE that allows you to transfer pictures or any file for that matter. This unfortunately means that you have to create your own which will not be an easy task. I recommend using another technology unless you're willing to spend significant time and effort until you can get a working solution.

Have a look at the links below:-

- [Bluetooth Low Energy serial: A valid design strategy?](https://punchthrough.com/serial-over-ble/)
- [Is there a serial port profile for BLE](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/12/is-there-a-serial-port-profile-for-ble)
- [Using BLE to replace Bluetooth classic SPP profile](https://os.mbed.com/questions/85849/Using-ble-to-replace-bluetooth-classic-S/)